# Unable to run CodeceptJS/Playwright test in a dockerized container - err: qemu: uncaught target signal 5 (Trace/breakpoint trap) - core dumped

Tags: docker, automated-tests, ui-automation, playwright, codeceptjs

I have a CodeceptJS/Playwright test framework which we want execute to in a Dockerized container. We have tried to implement the same using various base images but when execution starts we get

[image]

Here are various Docker images we have tried and we receive the same issue with qemu. We are running the script in M1 chip

`FROM adtoniq/xvfb-chrome:latest`

`FROM codeceptjs/codeceptjs`